# Does iOS support spannable strings?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any support for spannable string in iOS?
I would like to create an underlineSpan and on click of it and then open some other view controller.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSAttributedString *title;
title = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"hello how r u..." attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy-Bold" size:15], NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @1 , NSStrokeColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]}]; //1
UILabel *label;

label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( (self.view.bounds.size.width - title.size.width) / 2.0f, 40.0f, title.size.width, title.size.height)]; //2

label.attributedText = title; //3
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are called NSAttributedStrings in iOS.

Example Code to Add underline

```
NSString *str = @"Amit";
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
```

More info @ [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html)

To add link to that underline you check out this code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Google Webpage"];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName
                         value:@"http://www.google.com"
                         range:[[attributedString string] rangeOfString:@"Google Webpage"]];


NSDictionary *linkAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor],
                                 NSUnderlineColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor],
                                 NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlinePatternSolid)};

// assume that textView is a UITextView previously created (either by code or Interface Builder)
textView.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes; // customizes the appearance of links
textView.attributedText = attributedString;
textView.delegate = self;
```

This source code was found @ [Raywenderlich website](http://www.raywenderlich.com/48001/easily-overlooked-new-features-ios-7#textViewLinks)